# I want to delete all rows in a spreadsheet that do not have any value in the cells in Column A

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to delete all rows in a spreadsheet that do not have any value in the cells in Column A.
What is the script/formula for this function?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to preserve colors, fonts, etc, here is a simple solution:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var data  = range.getValues().filter(row => (row[0]));
range.clear().offset(0,0,data.length).setValues(data);
```